# How prove this $a_{1}=a_{2}=\cdots=a_{p}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

let $a_{1},\cdots,a_{p}$ be real numbers,and let $b_{1},b_{2},\cdots,b_{p}$ be distinct postive numbers with $b_{1}$ being the greatest of them,and such
$$\sum_{i=1}^{p}a_{i}b^k_{i}=0$$
for all natural numbers $k$.

show that:
$$a_{1}=a_{2}=\cdots=a_{p}=0$$

my try: since
$\begin{cases}a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+\cdots+a_{p}=0\\
a_{1}b_{1}+a_{2}b_{2}+\cdots+a_{p}b_{p}=0\\
a_{1}b^2_{1}+a_{2}b^2_{2}+\cdots+a_{p}b^2_{p}=0\\
\cdots\cdots\\
a_{1}b^n_{1}+a_{2}b^n_{2}+\cdots+a_{p}b^{n}_{p}=0\\
\cdots\cdots\cdots
\end{cases}$
then I can't prove $$a_{1}=a_{2}=\cdots=a_{p}=0$$

Comment: Hint: Use Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: Hint: Try to use matrix to represent this function and use Vandermonde determinant to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

The coefficients of your system for the $a_i$ form the Vandermonde matrix, which is invertible under your assumption that the $b_j$ are distinct.

However, you don't even need that. Notice that for $k \gg 1,$ the sum is dominated by the $a_1 b_1^k$ term, and therefore $a_1=0.$ Then keep going, to show that all the $a_i$ are zero.

Answer (score 0):

Applied Cramer's rule.$$a_i=\frac{\delta_i}{\delta}$$

where $\delta$ is Vandermonde's determinant nonzero and $\delta_i=0$